# How can I configure the Devise user lookup conditions for more than just email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, multi-tenant

I've been using the Devise gem for about 7 years now in an app of mine. I would like to convert this app into a multi-tenant type app where the same app responds to multiple domains (not subdomains).

In this setup a user may register and have an account with any domain that the app responds to. So there can be multiple entries in the users table for the same email address. These accounts will be scoped with a site_id attribute to distinguish them.

The main challenge using Devise for this setup is to understand how to set it up where the email address alone is not the unique identifier when it comes to signing in, resetting passwords and sending confirmation emails. It needs to always take into account email + site_id.

I think I've figured out how to use :authentication_keys for signing in, but I'm having trouble understanding how the lookup works for finding the user for password resetting and confirmations.

I'm obviously concerned about cross-domain contamination so I want to get it right. If Devise returns the wrong user (same email, different account) for something like password resetting, this would be bad.

Can someone point me in the right direction?